# Customising Joomla category blog

Tags: javascript, php, joomla3.0

I would like to change the link of an article within a category blog. I would like articles within the sub category to have links with a href="#" and apply a class to them. Whilst the parent category, or another sub category to link to their article as normal. I am a php and javascript beginner, but I have tried:

```
<?php $catid = JRequest::getInt('catid'); if ($catid == 11) : ?><?php echo JLayoutHelper::render('joomla.content.readmore', array('item' => $this->item, 'params' => $params, 'link' => $link)); ?><?php endif; ?>
```

Around the readmore call in the blog_item.php file. The result was that none of the items displayed a readmore button, even the ones within the relevant category.